# Custom combobox in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I need a custom Combobox in flex(as an ActionScript file), where I need to display in dropdown all the data nodes in the dataprovider as comma seperated values and when selecting only display one single node/value in textInput. How can we implemented this. Please help.

Thanks,
Rejeev.

Comment: Displaying the dataProvider as a comma separated list breaks normal UI Conventions.  How would the user select a single item from that list?  I suggest you rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:ComboBox id="fristname" x="283" y="63" 
    change="fistnameinput.text = fristname.text" width="160">
    <mx:ArrayCollection>
        <mx:String>Frist name</mx:String>
        <mx:String>Hardik</mx:String>
    </mx:ArrayCollection>
</mx:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Flex 4 you can do this with a custom Layout object, probably a variation of the HorizontalLayout.  To change the layout, create a new ComboBoxSkin copied from the default ComboBoxSkin and set the layout of the DataGroup.  You'll probably also want to create a custom ItemRenderer too to display the label with a comma.  Hope that helps.